# Discrete fourier transform of signal sampled from $\sin(x)$

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm new to fourier transform but I somewhat know fourier series. Since the fourier series of $\sin(2\pi t)$ is just $\sin(2\pi t)$, I thought of playing with this function to better understand what fourier transform is doing.

As a start I sampled $5$ points from $f(t)=\sin(2\pi t)$:
$$x=[0,1,0,-1,0]$$
[image]

From [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DFT%280%2C1%2C0%2C-1%2C0%29) it's fourier transform is
$$X=[0, 0.5 + 0.688191 i, -0.5 - 0.16246 i, -0.5 + 0.16246 i, 0.5 - 0.688191 i]$$

To my knowledge above numbers are the weights of the frequencies present in the original function.

- The first number $0$ says the dc component($0$ frequency) is $0$.
- Does the second number $ 0.5 + 0.688191 i$ represent the amplitude for $\sin(2\pi\cdot 1\cdot t)$?
- Similarly does the third number $ −0.5−0.16246i$ represent the amplitude for $\sin(2\pi\cdot 2\cdot t)$?

They don't make sense at all because the original function has only one frequency. Any help what these numbers represent for my specific example problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea in your message is almost correct. You have nevertheless to remind that, given $N$ the expansion function making a discrete Fourier function are defined on $\{0,N-1\}$, can be extended to be $N$ periodic, and are given by:

$f_k(i)=e^{\frac{2\pi}{N}ik}$

So you see that $f_k(0)=f_k(N)$. So here comes the first point: you do not have to include the last point in the Woflram input. If you do that you obtain:

${DFT([0, 1, 0, -1])}={[0, i, 0, -i]}  \  [1]$

which is already much nicer.

Why two frequencies? Well the functions on which you are expanding are complex! If you try:

${DFT([1, i, -1, -i])}={[0, 0, 0, 2]} \ [2]$

Tah dah. Can you see which $k$ I chose in the last example ? To understand better [1], remember that $f_1(i)+f_{-1}(i)$ is the sinus you have drawn (apart from constants)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the formula used here for the Discrete Fourier Transform is
\begin{equation}
X_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n=0}^4 x_n e^{-2 i \pi k n/5}
\qquad k = 0,\ldots,4
\end{equation}